# Page freeze for a few seconds after navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a MainPage.xaml (main menu) and the Game.xaml. If I navigate from Game.xaml to MainPage.xaml it freezes there for a few seconds. If I tap something on MainPage.xaml it run but after this huge delay. 
Game.xaml contains a lot of async tasks but the delay stay there even if no of the tasks is running. Any ideas where the problem could be or how I can avoid it? 
An app restart would be a solution but it's not possible.

Comment: Maybe you have something that makes the *Dispatcher* busy? Without the code it will be hard to find a solution.

Comment: Are you doing anything crazy in the constructor for the window? If so, consider moving it to the Load event.

Comment: No crazy things... the navigation from an other page to MainPage.xaml works well.

Comment: Actually I do not use a dispatcher. But is there a way to say kill all threads before navigate?

Comment: If you have some long running operations, then think of implementing CancellationToken and providing a way to cancel your task.